# Degree of pullback of covering map

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $p: E\to B$  be a covering map, $f: C\to B$ be a continuous onto map between compact manifolds, let
$$E'=E\times_B C=\{(c,e)|f(c)=p(e)\}$$
be the pullback with the projection $p': E'\to C$ and the other projection $f':E'\to E$. How to prove that the degree of $f'$ and the degree of $f$ coincide,i.e.,

$${\rm deg}\ f'= {\rm deg}\ f .$$

Could you please give me some help in detail? Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't you want $\deg p' = \deg p$?

Comment: @Rushy No，l want to have deg f'＝deg f@Rushy

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, $f$ is not necessarily a covering map. What is your definition of $\deg f$?

Comment: @Rushy f is not a covering, it's just a continuous map. The degree is the map degree which given by cohomology theory or any regular value of f in differential geometry, it's not the key point of the problem.

Comment: It's not clear how to define the degree, especially when $C, B$ are of different dimensions.

Comment: @ArcticChar Of course, they are of same dimension.

Comment: $p\circ f^{\prime}=f\circ p^{\prime}$ and degree is multiplicative.

Comment: @Thorgott Yeah, but how to say degree of p is equal degree of p'

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262335/degree-of-covering-map-between-orientable-manifolds